# DB2 compound statement using ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net, db2, ibm-midrange

I want to execute multiple statements from my data access layer using C# dan IBM's DB2 data provider.
(environment: DB2/AS400 os version: V5R4)

eg in TSQL:

```
declare varA integer;
select varA= count(*) from tableA;
select * from tableB where col1 <= varA
```

with SQL server ; I can concatenate those 3 statements into a string 
and assign the text to DBCommand.CommandText.

How to execute multiple statements(compound statement) against DB2 database via DBCommand (using IBM DB2 data provider)

I tried using begin and end block but still failed

```
BEGIN
statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
END
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it's possible.

I had already tried something similar some time ago, and the only solution I found is to dynamically create a stored procedure, calling it, and finally delete it.